# Xamarin Android - how to deploy different versions of same app on a single device using a powershell script to change package in manifest file?

Tags: android, visual-studio, powershell, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin App (Xamarin.Forms, but the App will be available only in Android) developed on Visual Studio 2015

My porpouse is to deploy to my testing tablet 2 versions of same App, one is a testing release, one is a production release.

I'm trying to do it launching debug on Visual Studio with tablet connected.

I understood that the goal is achieved if I change the package attribute in manifest file.

I tried manually, and everything seem to work as expected, everytime I change it, I receive a different new version of the app on my tablet.

Now I want to make it not manually.

I created 2 new configuration of build (build --> configuration manager), one for each version of the app I want to deploy

I write a script in powershell to change the attributes in the manifest file.
With the script I change even "application android:label", so I can check a new name on the App deployed. Launching it on powershell command prompt works perfectly.

I putted a call to this script in the prebuild event command of project properties in visual studio.

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "$(SolutionDir)Update-PackageName.ps1" $(ProjectDir) $(ConfigurationName)
```

The script receive the configuration name, so the package name will change depending on the configuration.

Something like this:

```
    param ([string] $ProjectDir, [string] $ConfigurationName)

    $ManifestPath = $ProjectDir + "Properties\AndroidManifest.xml"

    [xml] $xdoc = Get-Content $ManifestPath

    $package = $xdoc.manifest.package
    $appname = $xdoc.manifest.application.label

    $package = $package.Replace("TESTING_APP", "")
    $package = $package.Replace("RELEASE_APP", "")
    $appname = "SOME_NAME"

    If ($ConfigurationName -eq "TESTING_APP")
    { 
        $package = $package + "TESTING_APP" 
        $appname = "SOME_NAME_TESTING"
    }
    If ($ConfigurationName -eq "RELEASE_APP")
    { 
        $package = $package + "RELEASE_APP" 
        $appname = "SOME_NAME_RELEASE"
    }
    If ($package -ne $xdoc.manifest.package) 
    {
        $xdoc.manifest.package = $package
        $xdoc.manifest.application.label = $appname
        $xdoc.Save($ManifestPath)
    }
```

The script is called without problem, when I launch debugger I see the manifest changing as I wanted, the new app is deployed as expected.

The difference between changing manually the manifest file is that if the job is executed with the powershell script called in prebuild event command, I see the old App on the tablet disappearing.

Is it deleted?
Is it rewritten?
What I'm missing?